# How to use fields_view_get in Odoo 8?

Tags: python, xml, python-2.7, odoo-8, odoo

I'm trying to make a field `readonly` depending on a condition. This condition is that the user who opens the form belongs to a specific group (that's why I can't use `attrs` or `groups` to manage this).

What I did, and I'm pretty close to my purpose, is to overwrite `fields_view_get` method, check the condition, and alter the field if necessary.

```
@api.model
def fields_view_get(self, view_id=None, view_type='form', toolbar=False,
                    submenu=False):
    res = super(res_partner, self).fields_view_get(
        view_id=view_id, view_type=view_type, toolbar=toolbar,
        submenu=submenu)
    my_group_gid = self.env.ref(
        'my_module.my_group').id
    current_user_gids = self.env.user.groups_id.mapped('id')
    if view_type == 'form':
        if my_group_gid in current_user_gids:
            doc = etree.XML(res['arch'])
            the_fields = doc.xpath("//field[@name='my_field']")
            the_field = the_fields[0] if the_fields \
                else False
            the_field.set('readonly', '1')
            res['arch'] = etree.tostring(doc)
    return res
```

It seems to work well, because if I click on *Fields View Get* under the *Developer Mode*, the XML view code has been changed and I can see `<field name="the field" attrs= ... readonly="1"/>`. However, I always can edit the field.

I can't understand this very well, because there are other modules in which fields are modified exactly like this and they work.

Despite that, I keep trying and if instead of `readonly` attribute, I set `modifiers` in the following way, it works:

```
the_field.set('modifiers', '{"readonly": true}')
```

The problem: I'm totally overwriting all the modifiers of the field (like `attrs`, `required`, etc). So I want to update the `modifiers` attribute, not overwrite it. What I do is:

```
modifiers = the_field.get('modifiers')
```

When I try to convert the string `modifiers` to a dictionary, I get an error. This is the value of `modifiers`:

```
{"invisible": [["is_company", "=", true]]}
```

Can any one explain me why `the_field.set('readonly', '1')` is not working properly or why I cannot convert to a dictionary the variable `modifiers`?

**EDIT**

Ok, that variable is JSON data, so I should have converted it to a dictionary in a good way like this:

```
import json
modifiers_dict = json.loads(modifiers)
```

Now my question is only the first one:

Why can't I simply use `the_field.set('readonly', '1')` to manage my purpose?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This is what modifiers are](https://answers.launchpad.net/openobject-server/+question/168924)

Point is, openerp uses the `attrs` attribute into the view to setup accordingly the modifiers attribute, after that the `fields_view_get` is called, thus if you just change `attrs` it wouldn't work, then you need to change modifiers as well when you are within `fields_view_get`.

Comment: Thank you @Alessandro. It clarifies my question :)